# ComboBox Multibinding

Tags: wpf, combobox, multibinding

I'm pretty new to WPF.  I'm having a problem with a ComboBox

```
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" x:Name="ddlLocation" ItemsSource="{Binding Users.Locations}" Text="&lt;None Selected&gt;" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedValue="{Binding Users.SelectedUser.Location}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                            <Binding Path="Name" />
                            <Binding Path="ShortName" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <!--<ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                            <Binding Path="Name" />
                            <Binding Path="ShortName" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate>-->
    </ComboBox>
```

If I do this I get the typename in the selection box.  It seems like I should be able to use the SelectionBoxItemTemplate but it tells me SelectionBoxItemTemplate doesn't have an accessible setter. How would you do this?

Comment: Why you want to override `SelectionBoxItemTemplate`?

Comment: I want the text in the selection box to be the same as the text in the dropdown list.  I'm putting a WPF wrapper around some VB classes and they are sealed and I can't modify the code.

Comment: Setting `ItemTemplate` will do that. I tried in the sample and it works completely fine.

Comment: I'm getting the typename in the selection box instead of the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a result of having  `IsEditable="True"` which I would suggest removing, as you also have `IsReadOnly="True"`

Regarding the `Text` property --- a default value when nothing is selected... I'll just put this out there but am hoping someone has a better solution... I didn't see anything at a quick look online.

Include the namespace

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:StackOverflow.Converters"
```

Some xaml

```
<ComboBox ... IsEditable="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource NullBoolConverter}, FallbackValue=False}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <conv:NullBoolConverter x:Key="NullBoolConverter" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
```

Converter class

```
namespace StackOverflow.Converters
{
    class NullBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value == null;
        }
        ....
     }
}
```

Comment: Oh yup but if I take that off I don't see '<Not Selected>' any more.

Comment: I'll try that here in a bit.  Thanks for helping!